# Automating username and password entry for git pull of a remote repository (Bitbucket) on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket, pull

I am able to use this command successfully to step through each git repo (subfolder) in my directory:

`for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git pull; ); done`

This displays the folder name, changes into the directory, runs git pull, and then prompts me to enter my username and password.

I would like to be able to auto type in the user/PW since I have a lot of repos in the directory.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+cache+credentials

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to setup ssh authentication :
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/